# Issue Related to EXEC function in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have written some logical statements in Varchar variable as follows :

```
declare @P1 as varchar(max)
   set @P1 = ' (select (Convert(float,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  AttendanceMaster AS innerAM WHERE
                                            (AttendanceTypeId IN (SELECT  TypeId FROM AttendanceTypeMaster AS innerATM WHERE 
                                            innerAM.ParshadId = '+@ParshadId+'
                                            and (AttendanceSubjectId ='+Convert(varchar(5),@ASubjectId)+' ))) and innerAM.Attendance=''P1'''+ @innerWhereCondition +'))/6))'
```

Now I have executed above @P1 in Exec function as follows

```
    exec(@P1)
```

Now I want to get result of above @P1 statement which has been executing in EXEC function
and want to store in int variable. I have written above two statements in a user defined function and want to return int from above two statements.

How can I do this? Is it possible to assign results like this ?

```
Declare @result int

set @result = exec(@P1)
```

It throws an error saying: `incorrect syntext near Exec`

How can I return result from Exec function in a User-Defined Function in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `EXEC` in a user defined function.  Why are you trying to do this anyway?